# javascript div background color with important

Tags: javascript, css

Hi i been trying to change some divs style with javascript and it changes the style but if the divs display is changed to none and back to block it resets the style? i tried to fix this with important but that didn't seem to work? any ideas why this happens or if there is a better way i could achieve what i'm trying to do?

```
var Style = document.querySelectorAll('#mainui-features, #mainui-modes, #mainui-offers, #mainui-party, #mainui-play, #mainui-user, #mainui-settings');
for (var i = 0; i < Style.length; i++) {
  Style[i].style.borderRadius = '1em'; // standard
  Style[i].style.MozBorderRadius = '1em'; // Mozilla
  Style[i].style.WebkitBorderRadius = '1em'; // WebKitww
  Style[i].style.color = "#D35400";
  Style[i].style.border = "2px solid #D35400";
  Style[i].style.setProperty("background-image", "linear-gradient(to right, #92FE9D, #00C9FF)", "important");
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve] that shows the problem.

Comment: Please post relevant html and css code snippets too.

Comment: we'd need to see the HTML and CSS you're working with. Otherwise we've only got half the story

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inline styles you can a class

```js
var Style = document.querySelectorAll('#mainui-features, #mainui-modes, #mainui-offers, #mainui-party, #mainui-play, #mainui-user, #mainui-settings');
for (var i = 0; i < Style.length; i++) {
  Style[i].classList.add('styles')
}

function hide() {
  for (var i = 0; i < Style.length; i++) {
    Style[i].classList.add('hide')
  }
}

function show() {
  for (var i = 0; i < Style.length; i++) {
    Style[i].classList.remove('hide')
  }
}
```

```css
.styles {
  border-radius: 1em;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  color: #D35400;
  border: 2px solid #D35400;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #92FE9D, #00C9FF)
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="mainui-features">1</div>
<div id="mainui-modes">2</div>
<div id="mainui-offers">3</div>
<div id="mainui-party">4</div>


<button onclick="hide()">Hide</button>
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're doing wrong, but the way you describe your requirements works without any problem. Maybe this helps in some way.

I didn't include all the IDs.

```js
// Store all elements in an array
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll("#mainui-features, #mainui-modes, #mainui-offers, #mainui-party")];

// Assign CSS values to each element in the array
elements.map( el => {
  el.style.borderRadius = "1em";
  el.style.color = "#D35400";
  el.style.border = "2px solid #D35400";
  el.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to right, #92FE9D, #00C9FF)";
});

// Assign display:none to each element
elements.map( el => el.style.display = "none" );

// And make them display:block again
elements.map( el => el.style.display = "block" );
```

```css
div {
height: 1rem;
width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainui-features">1</div>
<div id="mainui-modes">2</div>
<div id="mainui-offers">3</div>
<div id="mainui-party">4</div>
```